# IntelliSense not working in React Native stylesheet after first item

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, flowtype, es6-modules

I am using VSCode (1.34.0) + <strike>Flow (Flow Language Support: 1.1.1, Flow Language Client: 0.2.1)</strike> *(switched to Typescript but still having the same error)* Typescript 3.4.5 on my React Native project.

When I start typing a style property, it completes the first property with no problem, then when I start typing the second style property, it doesn't complete:

[image: quick demo]

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** My (relevant) enabled extensions are:

- Babel JavaScript 0.0.22,
- <strike>Flow Language Support: 1.1.1,</strike>
- <strike>Flow Language Client: 0.2.1,</strike>
- npm Intellisense 1.3.0,
- Prettier - Code formatter 1.8.1,
- React Native Tools 0.9.3.

Comment: which extensions have you installed?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani updated the question.

Comment: "Visual Studio Code IntelliSense is provided for JavaScript, TypeScript, JSON, HTML, CSS, SCSS, and Less out of the box.". [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense). I disabled all my extensions, and Intellisense continued working.

Comment: Ok, another thing I noticed: my styles completions are detected as `Word`s, not `Attributes`. as referred [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird. I have no idea why. I totally forgot about this issue after installing many plugins and Vscode updates.

I don't know what was causing it but now on TypeScript 3.5.2/Vscode 1.36.1 with many plugins disabled, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Hi There I faced the same problem what I did is I
just installed a vs code  plugin named
IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML
and it solved the problem for me now it's working
The perfect link is here

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion